# C++ Read Access Violation in Singly Linked List

Tags: c++, struct, singly-linked-list

I'm writing a program about creating a list of country, there seems to no error in my code but when debugging, I get the error: Unhandled exception thrown: Read access violation p was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, after I  input some values.
Can anyone give me a hint or find me the mistake?

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

this is my struct Provice.

```
struct Province
{
    int Code;
    string Name;
    int Pop;
    float Area;
};
```

```
struct node
{
    struct Province data;
    node* next;
};
struct List
{
    node* head;
    node* tail;
};
void Init(List &l)
{
    l.head = NULL;
    l.tail = NULL;
}
void add_tail(List& l, node* p)
{
    if (l.head == NULL)
    {
        l.head = p;
        l.tail = p;
    }
    else
    {
        l.tail->next = p;
        l.tail = p;
    }
}
```

I think I got some problem when I create a node here without initializing value, is this right ?

```
void inputListProvinces(List& l)
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int i = 0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        node* p = new node;
        cin >> p->data.Code;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, p->data.Name);
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> p->data.Pop;
        cin >> p->data.Area;
        add_tail(l, p);
        i++;
    }
}
```

And the error happens here, but I dont know how to fix.

```
void outputListProvinces(List& l)
{
    node* p = l.head;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->data.Code << '\t'; /*Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
p was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF*/

        cout << p->data.Name << '\t';
        cout << p->data.Pop << '\t';
        cout << p->data.Area << '\t';
        cout << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }
}
void outputProvince(node* p)
{
    cout << p->data.Code << '\t';
    cout << p->data.Name << '\t';
    cout << p->data.Pop << '\t';
    cout << p->data.Area << '\t';
}
void outputProvincesMore1MillionPop(List& l)
{
    node* p = l.head;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->data.Pop > 1000)
        {
            outputProvince(p);
            cout << endl;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
}
node* findProMaxArea(List& l)
{
    node* n = l.head;
    node* p = l.head;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->data.Area > n->data.Area)
        {
            n = p;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    return n;
}



int main()
{
    List L;
    Init(L);
    inputListProvinces(L);
    cout << "List of provinces:" << endl;
    cout << "ID\t|Province\t|Population\t|Area" << endl;
    outputListProvinces(L);

    cout << "Provinces with a population of more than 1 million:" << endl;
    outputProvincesMore1MillionPop(L);

    cout << "The largest province:" << endl;
    node* p = findProMaxArea(L);
    if (p) outputProvince(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `L` is `NULL`... not sure exactly what you expected to happen here.

Comment: Unrelated: `std::getline` consumes the delimiter it finds. It's pretty rare to need an `ignore` after it.

Comment: If you *want* a singly linked list, use [std::forward_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). But honestly, *don't* use linked lists. Their performance suck.

Comment: Strongly consider making `Init` into `List`'s constructor. That way you can't forget to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistake is `node` never initializes its `next` pointer. You can only count on it being `NULL` if you set it to `NULL`, and the last `node` in the list MUST be `NULL`or the program can't find the end of the `List` and marches off into the wacky world of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Safest Fix: Add a constructor to `node` to make sure `next` is always initialized.

```cpp
struct node
{
    struct Province data;
    node* next;
    node(node* n = NULL): next(n)
    {
    }
};
```

There are other fixes, like making sure `l.tail->next = NULL;` at the end of `inputListProvinces`, but I don't think it's really worth the reduced overhead given the slow-ness of the console IO.

And if you do that, then you should also roll `Init` into `List` as a constructor:

```cpp
struct List
{
    node* head;
    node* tail;
    List(): head(NULL), tail(NULL)
    {
    }
};
```

This should leave you with the problem of a poorly-placed `cin.ignore()` consuming a character you don't want consumed.

Side note: Replace `NULL` with `nullptr` if available to your compiler and target C++ Standard revision. `nullptr` removes the bugs that can result from `NULL` being a glorified `0`.